# Analog Digital Converter in Android Phones ?

Tags: android

I am looking for specs for the Analog Digital Converter or to be more specific I look for the max. sampling rate from my phone. Is there a way to get the Information ? If not is there a way to get this information from a website (i tried google....) or a serious source? It is not so important for a special phone I would prefer any information on this topic to bring myself forward.

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(From developer.android.com regarding the AudioRecord class)

public AudioRecord (int audioSource, int sampleRateInHz, int channelConfig, int audioFormat, int bufferSizeInBytes)

developer.android.com states "sampleRateInHz    the sample rate expressed in Hertz. 44100Hz is currently the only rate that is guaranteed to work on all devices, but other rates such as 22050, 16000, and 11025 may work on some devices."

It doesn't look like there's a way to poll the phone for the samplerate, but you can use 44100Hz and it will be guaranteed to work on any device.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, any device with a mic input can be used as an "oscilloscope" either actively (with appropriate software) or the data can be "stored" and analyzed later.

As most people might remember from high school science: Human hearing ranges from 20 Hz to 20 kHz. Also, as any engineer who has studied Control theory would know, in order to effectively sample / control / measure a signal your sampling frequency has to be above the Nyquist frequency, which is usually 2 times the maximum frequency of the signal that you want to measure.

Now combine these two facts: Most good audio systems have a max rated mic input frequency of 44.1kHz - which is actually a little more than 2.2 times (Nyquist theory says it has to be greater than 2 times) the maximum human hearing (20 kHz).

So, if you have a device that is rated to 44.1 kHz you can safely "read" signals from 20 Hz to 22 kHz. If it is rated frequency of the input device is 22 kHz, then you should be able to "read" signals from 20 Hz to 11 kHz. BUT one critical aspect is that the "response" is often "balanced" to human speech. In other words, if you have a signal of 3V input signal at 20 Hz, then it may be "read" by the phone differently than if you applied a 3V signal at 1 kHz. You have to look at the response curve of the microphone + internal electronics and calibrate it using known signals.